# GNU Screen doesn't work for split window

Tags: gnu-screen

My mac is installed with `screen`, when I type `screen`, it prompted with the version `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`.

I have multiple sessions created:

```
bash-3.2$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    1956.ttys016.14109fd63c85       (Attached)
    2187.ttys011.14109fd63c85       (Attached)
    34569.diyu      (Detached)
    34739.diyuanother       (Attached)
    35330.ttys001.14109fd63c85      (Detached)
    35338.diyu      (Attached)
    39155.ttys011.14109fd63c85      (Detached)
```

7 Sockets in /var/folders/wz/yz_xgny505g9hq089fry6hknlzvxbn/T/.screen.

`Ctrl-a S` supposed to split the current region horizontally, but when I type `control A shift S` on my mac keyboard, nothing happens. Also doesn't work for `control A S`.

Comment: Press `C-a :`, enter `split` and press Return, does it work?

Comment: Doesn't work. I notice that when I press `Control a`, it shows "No Other Window". But we I do a `Screen -ls`, I can see multiple windows attached.